# Media queries in code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a asp.net custom built calender working on a bootstrap page.
On desktop view it shows the full month 5 weeks max which is all fine using the below as weeks.

```
 IList<int> weekList = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    weekList.Add(i);
 }
 WeekRepeater.DataSource = weekList;
 WeekRepeater.DataBind();
```

However on mobile view, Can i determine on code behind if it is under a certain resolution, i use this logic to show only 1 week not 5.

```
IList<int> weekList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    weekList.Add(i);
}
WeekRepeater.DataSource = weekList;
WeekRepeater.DataBind();
```

Then a button when pressed will show all 5 weeks - so back to the original logic.

Is there a way to achieve this? possibly the same way as bootstrap/media queries?

Comment: you cannot use media queries in code behind , because server can't find the resolution of the page/ browser before rendering the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i thought not. is there an alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: just google it ,there are many date/time picker plugins